# What is the agama/tantra being followed at the Sri Krishna temple at Guruvayur in Kerala?

Tags: rituals, temple, agamas

When were the rituals in [Sri Krishna temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guruvayur_Temple) at Guruvayur, Kerala standardized to current form? Who was responsible for that? Which agamas/tantras are followed in the temple while performing rituals to the deity?

Comment: I don't think they follow Agamas at Guruvayur, they probably follow one or another Rahasya Vishnu Tantra.

Comment: Ok. I added tantras to the question wording to improve clarity.

Comment: It was standardised by Chennas Narayanan Namputiripad.